# Using ModiTect to generate module info and create runtime image

Tags: java, maven, graphviz, jlink, moditect

Tried to use JLink to create a runtime image, however:

```
Error: automatic module cannot be used with JLink: graphviz.java
```

I'm using the following [library](https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java) which has only automatic modules.

Did some searches, and it seems that I can use [ModiTect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect)  to generate module-info for the library and create a runtime image.

However, as I am new to modules I couldn't figure it out.
I guess I would need a more in-depth explanation then what I could find on ModiTect's GitHub page.

my modules-info.java:

```java
module elitonlais {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires graphviz.java;

    opens elitonlais to javafx.fxml;
    opens elitonlais.controller to javafx.fxml;
    opens elitonlais.model to javafx.fxml;

    exports elitonlais;
    exports elitonlais.controller;
    exports elitonlais.model;
}
```

My pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>elitonlais</groupId>
    <artifactId>minafd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>guru.nidi</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphviz-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>elitonlais.App</mainClass>
                    <launcher>launch.sh</launcher>
                    <compress>2</compress>
                    <jlinkZipName>MinAFD</jlinkZipName>
                    <jlinkImageName>MinAFD</jlinkImageName>
                    <includePathExceptionsInClasspath>true</includePathExceptionsInClasspath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
                <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-runtime-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <modulePath>
                                <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
                            </modulePath>
                            <modules>
                                <module>module-info.java</module>
                                <!--   <module>javafx.controls</module>
                                <module>javafx.graphics</module> -->
                            </modules>
                            <launcher>
                                <name>test33</name>
                                <module>module-info.java/elitonlais.app</module>
                            </launcher>
                            <compression>2</compression>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jlink-image</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The entire project structure:
https://github.com/EMachad0/MinAFD

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add it following the documentation at the link [Adding module descriptors to existing JAR files](https://github.com/moditect/moditect#adding-module-descriptors-to-existing-jar-files).

Adding the following to your existing `pom.xml` as an additional `<execution>` step for ModiTect should work:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <!-- your existing code here -->
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>add-module-infos</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-module-info</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
            <modules>
                <module>
                    <artifact>
                        <groupId>guru.nidi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>graphviz-java</artifactId>
                        <version>0.17.0</version>
                    </artifact>
                    <!-- only use one of either moduleInfo or moduleInfoSource -->
                    <moduleInfo>
                        <name>guru.nidi.graphviz</name>
                        <exports>
                            *;
                        </exports>
                        <!-- possibly other fine-tuning -->
                    </moduleInfo>
                    <!-- only use one of either moduleInfo or moduleInfoSource -->
                    <moduleInfoSource>
                        module guru.nidi.graphviz {
                            requires ...;
                            exports ...;
                            provides ...
                                with ...;
                        }
                    </moduleInfoSource>
                    <!-- or use moduleInfoFile instead of the above -->
                </module>
                <module>
                    ...
                </module>
            </modules>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Note also that the project has specified an automatic module name of `guru.nidi.graphviz` so you'll need to change your own `module-info` to require that, rather than the auto-derived `graphviz.java`.

Comment: How i am supossed to execute the goals?
Running moditect:create-runtime-info gives me this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Beta2:create-runtime-image (default-cli) on project MinAFD: The parameters 'modules' for goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Beta2:create-runtime-image are missing or invalid
```

Comment: There is a separate configuration you need to run the `create-runtime-info` goal.  But the other goal should run during the `generate-resources` phase of your build.

Comment: If you don't want it during your build, does the goal `moditect:add-module-info` not add the class to the existing JAR?